# Question on the support of a vector fields, and on the set of critical points

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a smooth differential manifold, and let $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ be a smooth vector field.
The support $supp(X)$ of $X$ is defined as the closure, in $M$, of the set $A(X):=\{m\in M: X(m)\neq 0\}$.
I am not sure to be able to correctly ``see'' $supp(X)$ even for simple vector fields.
For example, if $M=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with cartesian coordinates $(x\,;y)$, and $X=y\partial_{x}$, it is evident that $A(X)$ is the complement of the $x$-axis.
In this case, since every open neighbourhood of a point on the $x$-axis contains a point in $A$, I think that $supp(X)=M$.
However, this line of reasoning leads me to think that if $X$ is globally defined on $M$, then $supp(X)=M$.
Is it true?

Furthermore, I am concretely interested in the set of critical points of $X$ defined as $Z(X):=\{m\in M: X(m)=0\}$, and I would like to know if it is closed or not.
I am sorry for not having any personal thought on this, but, at the moment, I seem to be unable to come up with anything at all.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this line of reasoning leads me to think that if $X$ is globally defined on $M$, then $supp(X)=M$. Is it true?

Of course not, consider the zero vector field. The picture you should have in your head is pretty clear from the definition - $\mathrm{supp}(X)$ is the smallest closed set that contains all the points where $X$ is non-zero. So the only vector fields whose support is all of $M$ are those that are non-zero on a dense set.

Regarding your second question, remember from topology that since $X$ is continuous, the preimage under $X$ of a closed set is closed.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. However, I have some doubts. Concerning the first part of the answer and the example $X=y\partial_{x}$ I gave, what is the closure of $A(X)$? Concerning the second part of Your answer, how can You say that the image through $X$ of $Z(X)$ is closed?

Comment: @Ilcapitano: In that example,$A(X)$ is the complement of the $x$-axis, so the closure is the whole space. Regarding the second question: the set of zero vectors in the tangent bundle is closed. It's probably easiest to prove this in coordinates, where zero is literally just $0 \in \mathbb R^n$, so you're taking the preimage of a (n obviously closed) singleton.